# Angular typescript observable with get/set

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I want to get and set data from observable but I want to have possibility to subscribe too.

Can I do something like this or is there better approach?

```
public $someName: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

    set someName(value: string) {
        if (this.$someName.value != value) {
            this.$someName.next(value);
        }
    }

    get someName() {
        return this.$someName.value;
    }
```

Now I can access $someName observable and someName get/set. So is there some better approach?

Comment: I think this is a viable solution to your problem, are you just asking about best practice or are you worried something might break?

Comment: @Tommi I am trying to find best solution like best practice maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a another getter like this

```
get sameNameChange(){

  return this.$someName.asObservable();

}
```